# No default engine was specified and no extension was provided error is thrown by terminal

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, mongodb

i am trying to execute a backend program in nodejs and i am using mongodb.i am creating a form where just 2 input fields are there password and name.  am not using any hbs or ejs and has no default engine,but my vs code terminal shows

```
"No default engine was specified and no extension was provided.
    at new View (C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\adin\backend\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:61:11)
    at Function.render (C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\adin\backend\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:587:12)
    at ServerResponse.render (C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\adin\backend\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1039:7)
    at C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\adin\backend\src\app.js:46:25
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)"


app.js

const static_path =path.join(__dirname,"../public");

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false })); 
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static(static_path));

app.get("/",(req,res)=>{
    res.render("index");
});

app.get("/index",(req,res)=>{
    res.render("index");
})


//create a new user in database
app.post("/index",async (req,res)=>{
    try{
        const indexSchema=new Index({
            name: req.body.name,
            password: req.body.password
        });

        const indexed=await indexSchema.save();
        res.status(201).render("index");
        
    }catch(error){
        res.status(400).send(error);
        console.log(error);
    }
})


app.listen(port, ()=>{
    console.log(`server is running at port no ${port}`);
})
```

Comment: What research have you done on the error and what have you done to try to resolve the issue? That error message seems to have a lot of results on this site

Comment: i am not using any template engine .. so how should i use the view engine without any jade ejs or hbs .....?

Comment: If you're not using a view engine (so no template engine), then don't use `res.render()`.  Use `res.sendFile()` instead and you must pass a full path and the file you're sending must be a complete HTML file on its own.  `res.render()` requires a template engine be registered.